# Viewpager swipe not working with recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, swipe

I have a `ViewPager` and `RecyclerView` in the same Activity and both of these views overlapping (`RecyclerView` is on front and `ViewPager` is on behind). My `ViewPager` swipe works correctly when I swipe on empty space, but when I swipe on `RecyclerView`, viewpager swipe doesn't work. I have button and seekbar in `Recyclerview`. I want to ViewPager swipe when user also swipe over RecyclerView except seekbar.

My layout is:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imagesLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timerLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="none" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

And my java code is :

```
 imagesRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        int numberOfColumns = 3;
        imagesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, numberOfColumns));
        imagesRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);
        imagesRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
```

I searched a lot about this topic but i cant find any solution.My viewpager adapter looks like:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    FragmentManager fm;
    private SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm=fm;


    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = new ImageFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putSerializable("TabObject", Constants.tabs.get(position));

        fragment.setArguments(args);


        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Constants.tabs.size();
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public List<Fragment> getFragments(){
        return fm.getFragments();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof ImageFragment) {
            // Create a new method notifyUpdate() in your fragment
            // it will get call when you invoke
            // notifyDatasetChaged();
          //  ((SoundsFragment) object).updateGridData();
        }
        //don't return POSITION_NONE, avoid fragment recreation.
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wait, please elaborate a little bit more. Both of these are in the same Activity, what do you mean you can swipe on ViewPager and not on RecyclerView Did you create an adapter? Did you hook the adapter up to the RecyclerView?

Comment: I use viewpager for backgroundImages.When I swipe different categories opens.

Comment: I want to swipe on viewpager only.It works goog when i swipe empty space but when i swipe on RecyclerView, viewpager swipe not working. I create adapter both of viewpager and recylerview.

Comment: I think it's something in your adapter. Please post code

Comment: I updated my question and added adapter

Answer (score 0):

you can use

1)

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);
```

2)inside your recylerView tag

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```